# Upgrading Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Data Access Layer solution built in Visual Studio 2010. It uses Entity Data Model (.edmx files) to create object models of the data.

It is built with .Net 3.5 framework so I assume this is also version 3.5 of Entity Framework?

We use a number of TVFs to return datasets and unfortunately EF 3.5 does not provide access to TVFs. So we have has to build tsql views that call those TVFs.

Is it possible to upgrade this solution to EF 6 and use TVFs? What are the steps involved?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has release a guide to do. You find it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx

It involves getting the latest assemblies and do some modifications in order to run. It seems upgrading from an older version is a little harder than from a new version.